# My Hook functions stop working

Tags: delphi, hook, global

After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again

Function of KeyboardHook

```
function KeyboardHook(Code: Integer; wParam : WPARAM; lParam : LPARAM): LongInt;
var
  Buffer: TEventMsg;
  Key: Cardinal;
begin
  if (wParam = $0101) and
     (App.Inside) then
  begin
    Buffer := PEventMsg(lParam)^;
    Key := Buffer.message;

    if App.Inside then
    begin
      case Key of
        VK_NEXT: App.Next;
        VK_CAPITAL: App.Show;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  CallNextHookEx(Hook_ID_Keyboard, Code, wParam, lParam);
  Result := 0;
end;
```

Function to start the Hook

```
function StartHookKeyboard: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Hook_ID_Keyboard := SetWindowsHookEx(13, @KeyboardHook, HInstance, 0);
  If Hook_ID_Keyboard = 0  then
    Result := False else
    Result := True;
end;
```

Is there any error in my code?

Comment: Repeating *After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again* several times is not a question. Copying and pasting *After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again* is not a question. Copying and pasting *After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again After a while crashes and I have to start the hook again* is not a question. Please [edit] and try again.

Comment: Writing *so I'm writing this paragraph useless to publish it* is just as wrong as copying and pasting nonsense. There's a requirement for a certain amount of text so that you'll provide **useful** information, not noise. If you don't want to participate here by doing things right, go somewhere else to find help.

Comment: One more try. Where are you putting your keyboard hook code? How can we use the code you've posted to make this problem happen? (Copying and pasting it into a Delphi unit won't work, because we don't have any code that calls the function.) Please [edit] to provide a MCVE that we can use to debug the problem. You've provided half the information and said "my code stops working. Is there any error?*. How can we get the code you posted to execute so we can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use hard-coded [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). In this context, 13 is `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, `$0101` is `WM_KEYUP`, etc. Use the actual names in your code. They are declared in the `Windows`  and `Messages` units.

Did you declare `KeyboardHook()` to use the `stdcall` calling convention?  The code you have shown is not doing so.  This is very important so the parameter values are passed correctly on the call stack.

The `lParam` value of a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook is NOT a `PEventMsg` (pointer to an [`EVENTMSG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644966.aspx) structure). That structure is used for `WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK` hooks. `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` uses the [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx) structure instead.  Delphi does not declare that particular structure, so you will have to declare it yourself in your code.

And don't ignore the callback's `Code` parameter, or the return value of `CallNextHookEx()`.  They are important.  The `wParam` and `lParam` values are only valid when the `Code` parameter is `HC_ACTION` (0).  And the return value of `CallNextHookEx()` needs to be passed up the hook chain.

Try this instead:

```
type
  PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = ^KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = record
    vkCode: DWORD;
    scanCode: DWORD;
    flags: DWORD;
    time: DWORD;
    dwExtraInfo: ULONG_PTR;
  end;

function KeyboardHook(Code: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if Code = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    if (wParam = WM_KEYUP) and (App.Inside) then
    begin
      case PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT(lParam)^.vkCode of
        VK_NEXT: App.Next;
        VK_CAPITAL: App.Show;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  // note that CallNextHookEx() ignores the first parameter,
  // so you could pass 0 instead of ID_Keyboard...
  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook_ID_Keyboard, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

function StartHookKeyboard: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  if Hook_ID_Keyboard = 0 then
    Hook_ID_Keyboard := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, @KeyboardHook, HInstance, 0);
  Result := Hook_ID_Keyboard <> 0;
end;

function StopHookKeyboard: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  if Hook_ID_Keyboard <> 0 then
  begin
    if UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook_ID_Keyboard) then
      Hook_ID_Keyboard := 0;
  end;
  Result := Hook_ID_Keyboard = 0;
end;
```

If the code is still crashing, it is likely related to `App`.  What is `App`?  Where and how is it declared?  How is it initialized?  What do `Next()` and `Show()` actually do?  You are installing the hook globally to hook all running processes, so is `App` being used in a cross-process-safe manner?

Comment: I'm using Delphi 7 and WH_KEYBOARD_LL don't exist's
But, the code work and the error is in "App.Show".

Comment: Either your `App` pointer is not valid, or `Show()` is doing something it should not be doing. Either way, you have not shown any code related to how you setup `App` or what `Show()` does.  So nobody here can tell you why your code is failing.

Comment: No problem, I found the error inside App.Show and fix. Thx all any way. And sorry for my english.